# MongoDB JavaScript Yield large set of results

Tags: javascript, python, mongodb, yield

I'm trying to query a large set of results from a MongoDB over Python. I do this via JavaScript, because I want to get something like the grandchildren in a tree-like structure. My code looks like the following:

```
col = db.getCollection(...)
var res = new Array();
col.find( { "type" : ["example"] } ).forEach(
  function(entry) 
  {
    v1 = col.find( {"_id" : entry["..."]} )
    ... (walk through the structure) ...
    vn = ...
    res.push([v1["_id"], vn["data"]]);
  } 
);         
return res;
```

Now, I'm having the problem, that the resulting array becomes very (too) large and the memory gets exceeded. Is there a way, to yield the results instead of pushing them into an array?

Comment: Use `next` instead of `forEach`? Do one result at a time.

Comment: Can you clarify what you would like to accomplish with your yield? If the goal is to perform an operation in batches, you could keep a counter of records you have pushed to array. When you reach the batch size you would then operate on the current record set and then clear the array after.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I would like to do a complex query on the server side and get all results to work with on python-side, afterwards. If I get you right, it would only be possible to work with the small arrays on server side or give one of them back as a result, so that multiple queries would be needed. I would like to process all results on client side and therefor give the results back, batch for batch.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I think I know, what you mean. I created a structure like the following:

```
var bulksize = 1000;
var col = db.getCollection("..");       
var queryRes = col.find( { ... } )

process = function(entity) { ... }

nextEntries = function()
{
  var res = new Array();
  for(var i=0; i<bulksize; i++)
  {            
    if(hasNext())
      res.push(process(queryRes.next()));
    else
      break;
  }  
  return res;
}

hasNext = function()
{
  return queryRes.hasNext();
}
```

The script separates the results into bulks of 1000 entries. And from Python side eval the noted script and then I do the following:

```
while database.eval('hasNext()'):
    print "test"
    for res in database.eval('return nextEntries()'):
        doSth(res)
```

The interesting thing is, that the console always says:

```
test
test
test
test
test
test
```

Then I get the error:

```
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: command SON([('$eval', Code('return nextEntries()', {})), ('args', ())]) failed: invoke failed: JS Error: ReferenceError: nextEntries is not defined nofile_a:0
```

This means, that the first calls of nextEntries() work, but then the function is not there, anymore. Could it be, that MongoDB does something like a clearing of the JavaScript cache? The problem does not depend on the bulksize (tested with 10, 100, 1000, 10000 and always the same result).

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I found a line in the source code of MongoDB, which clears all JavaScripts that are used more than 10 times. So if no changes on the database server are wanted, it is necessary to query the database multiple times and send bulks to the client by selecting amounts of items with help of the skip() and limit() functions. This works surprisingly fast. Thanks for your help.